# How long should exporting a snapshot take?

Tags: node, storage, snapshots

If `tezos-node snapshot export ...` is supposed to make a ~2GB snapshot, at the speed it is going for me it will take weeks to complete. How long should this take? Exporting a rolling snapshot doesn't seem faster.

If this is not supposed to be super slow, how can I diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question essentially depends on your hardware setup. As you may know, blockchain full nodes are usually pretty intense on disk io so if you are using an old HDD you may likely suffer.

But with a recent SSD drive a snapshot of block 458815 too less than 5 mins to generate.